# Invisible FileUpload control causes error on javascript postback in IE

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, webforms

I have asp.net webforms page with Fileupload control and image. When user clicks on image I trigger FileUpload click and when clicking ok I call __doPostBack on client side. If FileUpload is visible it works fine, but when I set `style='visibility: hidden'` or `display: none` - javascript gives error: access denied! It reproduces only in IE, not FF or chrome. Could anybody tell me how to avoid this and post the file to server? I have tried input type='file' with runat='server', non-server input-file - the result is the same...

HTML:

```
<input id="_ctl00_fuplImage" type="file" style="visibility: hidden" name="$ctl00$fuplImage">
```

JavaScript:

```
var fileupload = $('#<%= fuplImage.ClientID %>');

$('#<%= imgPhoto.ClientID %>').click(function() {
    fileupload.click();
});

fileupload.change(function() {
    var val = fileupload.val();
    if (val == '') return;
    __doPostBack(fileupload.attr('id'), val);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML source code for that FileUpload control?

Comment: <input id="_ctl00_fuplImage" type="file" style="visibility: hidden" name="$ctl00$fuplImage"> ...

Comment: How do you trigger the FileUpload click? It seems that some sort of security mechanism prevents you from triggering clicks on hidden file-fields.

Comment: var fileupload = $('#<%= fuplImage.ClientID %>');
$('#<%= imgPhoto.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    fileupload.click();
});
        fileupload.change(function () {
            var val = fileupload.val();
            if (val == '') return;
            __doPostBack(fileupload.attr('id'), val);
        });

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NjgDR/3/ I've tested this demo in IE7, IE8, and IE9. When I click the image, the "Choose file" window pops up normally. No "access denied" error is thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unresolvable security issue of IE (only) that does not allow to send form with hidden file upload input. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I see. Triggering the click is not an issue, but it's the form submit that throws the error.