# jquery-ui dialog box not posting in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jquery ui dialog box that contains a bunch of asp.net controls. There is a runat="server" button in the dialog box as well that posts the form to the server. This is unfortunately not working in IE. In Chrome, it's working as expected. Here are the relevant code snippets...

```
$("#applicationFormDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 780,
                height: 550,
                title: 'Please enter your career details',
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(".uploadYourResume").css('display', 'none');
                    clearAllControls();
                    var indexToSelect = $('#applicationFormDialog').data('indexVal');
                    $("#" + "<%=ddlPosition.ClientID %>" + " option")[indexToSelect].selected = true;
                    debugger;
                    $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
                },
                beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                    clearAllControls();
                },
                resizable: false
        });
```

jQuery UI version = 1.10.1
jQuery version = 1.9.1

Let me know if there is anything else you need from me.

**Update**: This works if I simply put a normal submit button with runat='server', but I'm validating the form on the client side before submitting it, and that is where I believe the problem is. This is the client side validation method.

```
function validateForm() {
            // Clear all error divs...
            $(".errorSpan").css('display', 'none');

            // Build the array.            
            var arrayOfCtrls = new Array();

            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtName.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));                        // Name
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));                       // Email
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtCity.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));                        // City
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= ddlState.ClientID %>", "", "dropdown", 0));                      // State
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= uploadResume.ClientID %>", "fileUploadErrorSpan", "file", 0));   // Resume
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= ddlPosition.ClientID %>", "", "dropdown", 0));                   // Position
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= ddlQualification.ClientID %>", "", "dropdown", 0));              // Qualification
            arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= ddlExperience.ClientID %>", "", "dropdown", 0));                 // Experience


            if ($("#" + "<%=ddlExperience.ClientID %>").val() != "Fresher") {
                arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtCurrCompany.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));     // Current Company
                arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtWorkingSince.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));    // Working since                        
                arrayOfCtrls.push(new control("<%= txtCurrLocation.ClientID %>", "", "textbox", 0));    // Current Location            
            }

            if (!controlsToValidate(arrayOfCtrls)) {
                return false;
            }
            // Check email address
            if (!validEmail((document.getElementById("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>")).value)) {
                document.getElementById("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>").focus();
                document.getElementById("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>").title = "Please enter a proper email address.";
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

These are the buttons on the dialog box

```
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitForm" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validateForm()" OnClick="submitForm_Click" />
            <input type="button" id="btnClearFields" value="Clear" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server"/>
```

The last button I added to check if postback was working for a normal button, and it is working fine.

UPDATE #2: There is a problem, some jquery method keeps getting called after I return true from the script.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you remove all the JS from inside of validateForm() method, and simply return true instead?

Comment: No it wasn't. I fixed the problem though. Check the answer below. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm going to answer this myself, since nothing has been posted here, partly because of the fact that the information that I gave was **insufficient**.

In the form that I had made, there was a file upload control that I was hiding because I wanted to style it. I had then placed two buttons, **Select...** and **Clear** in it's place.

Anyways [according to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12058731/903324) IE will not post to the server, if a file upload control is hidden. So that's what was happening.

I had no way of knowing that, that was the issue, so I'm sorry for the lack of information on the original post.